# How can I cancel and replace a Transaction that never gets confirmed?

Tags: transactions, block, transaction-fees, multi-signature

According this this WikiPage, [a MultiSigTransaction that doesn't include a fee may never get included in a block.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions#Multisignature_transactions)

Since I've read that replacing Transactions (by version number or any other feature) isn't enabled, how can I expedite the replacement and updating of this?

Answer (score 3):

You could import the private keys used into another wallet and spend the funds there.  For instance, on Blockchain.info/wallet you simply do Advanced -> Import and import the private keys (which can be exported from Bitcoin-Qt's debug console).

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at this, from a very simplistic approach.

The best way to replace it is to pretend it didn't happen. Reset the blockchain in use, and continue as normal. The client (or `bitcoind`) will be unaware of the transaction, and the mistake transaction will eventually be disregarded by all nodes, invalidated, and discarded.